# Send e-mail in C# ASP.NET with parameters passed in from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email

I should mention this is just a learning project, and will never be hosted online. I am running the app locally.

I'm having two problems sending email with parameters passed in:

1. The main problem: it doesn't send.
2. The parameters don't populate the form in the view until after clicking send and redirecting to the same page, however they are displaying in the URL.

Here is my code:

Mail.cs (Model)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace LotManager.Models
{
    public class Mail
    {
        public string From = "myusername@gmail.com";
        public string To { get; set; }
        public string Subject = "Parking Alert";
        public string Body { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

MailController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using LotManager.Controllers;

namespace LotManager.Controllers
{
    public class MailController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /SendMailer/  
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult Index(LotManager.Models.Mail _objModelMail)
        {
            var to = Request.QueryString["To"];
            ViewBag.To = to;
            var body = Request.QueryString["Body"];
            ViewBag.Body = body;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.To.Add(to);                
                mail.From = new MailAddress(_objModelMail.From);
                string Body = body;
                mail.Body = Body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 25;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
                ("mygmailusername", "mypassword"); //My actual account info goes here
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                try
                {
                    smtp.Send(mail);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The email was not sent, because I couldn't get it to work. Oops!");
                }
                return View("Index", _objModelMail);
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml (Send Mail View)

```
@model LotManager.Models.Mail

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Send";
}

<h2>Send</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <p>To: </p>
    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.To, new { @Value = @ViewBag.To })</p>
    <p>Body: </p>
    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Body, new { @Value = @ViewBag.Body })</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}
```

The code that passes the parameters to the URL:

```
@Html.Actionlink("Send Notification", "Index", "Mail", new { To = item.Employee.Email, Body = item.Description }, null)
```

Comment: Is there an exception, or does the email just not arrive?

Comment: The email just doesn't arrive. I forgot to mention that I'm hosting this locally, as it's just a learning project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A malicious user can use your page to spam people using your email account.  That will quickly destroy your sender reputation with Gmail.  It can be nearly impossible to recover from a badly tarnished sender reputation.

**Issue 1**

You're using the [wrong SMTP port](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en).

smtp.gmail.com requires port 465 for SSL or port 587 for TLS.

**Issue 2**

You are invoking the controller using a link (ActionLink), which creates a GET request.  Your controller action will only be invoked for a POST however due to the [HttpPost] attribute.  Either remove [HttpPost], or use a post action rather than a link to invoke the controller action.

Comment: I've tried port 25, 465, and 587 with no luck. I forgot to mention that I'm running this locally only, as it is just a learning project. Thanks.

Comment: Did you fix Issue 2?  Are you sure the sending code is being called? `I'm running this locally`  Some ISPs block Port 25 to SMTP servers other than their own to control spam, though I have never heard of an ISP blocking 465 or 587.  Check whether you have an outbound firewall rule preventing the connection.

Comment: Try downloading an email client like Mozilla Thunderbird.  Configure it the same way as your code (same SMTP, user, password, port, protocol).  See if you can send an email using the client.  If sending fails, you should get a reasonably detailed error message.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are nor avialliable, becasue You are using `[HttpPost]`. Paramters are visible in GET not in POST.

About second problem look at Google documentation: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en
If you want to use port 25 you need to change server to `smtp-relay.gmail.com`. Otherwise change port to 465 for SSL or port 587 for TLS.

Comment: I've tried port 25 with smtp-relay and aspmx.l.google.com, and 465 and 587 with smtp.gmail.com with no luck. I forgot to mention that I'm running this locally, which may be the problem.